# How import libraries work exactly?

Tags: c++

I've heard that import libraries have "stubs" so the executable knows which dll and function we want. Now my question is: What are those stubs? What do they look like? How does the executable set the pointers to right places in the DLL? And how does it know if we are talking about normal library or import library since they both are .lib files?

Comment: See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx

Comment: The executable doesn't know any of this. It's the linker that does, and it emits appropriate code.

Answer (score 8):

The MSVC linker does not link directly to a DLL, it can only link to a static library (.lib).

Very roughly speaking, an import library is a normal static library, that has a stub function for every DLL exported function.

For example, if a DLL has a function `void func1()` and exports `func1`, the corresponding import library will contain a stub function `void __imp__func1() { __asm { jmp dword ptr func1; } }`

At run time, the "jump" will take the address of `func1` from the import table. That's why a stub is needed.

The declaration `void __declspec(dllimport) func1();` in your application will in fact refer to `__imp__func1()`.

You can bypass this whole mechanism altogether and call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get the address of `func1` at run time. It will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the compiler (linker) and platform you are using.

I.e. on Windows OS, a shared library is usually a .DLL file,
if you want to link to it (other than dynamically loading it and resolve its symbols at runtime), you need the corresponding .LIB file, that is the stub library.

Basically a stub library is a static library that re-maps all the symbols exported by the DLL (with `__declspec(dllexport)`) to symbols present in the stub and that can be found and statically linked within your program by using `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Comment: So is __declspec(dllexport) a function from Windows API or is it an instruction that is in the Visual Studio?

Comment: @Daniel Nyman: '__declspec' is a keyword (as far as I know specific for Visual Studio), 'dllexport' and 'dllimport' are attributes of that keyword. See more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx

Comment: [__declspec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx) is a keyword, that assigns a Microsoft-specific storage-class attribute.